# Awk print matched column if exists else print not found

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My text file looks like below

```
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100 outbound=100
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22  outbound=100
```

I am using the below awk code to print the matched string and extract whatever is after the "=".

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/inbound=/)print $(i)}'  | cut -d : -f1 | cut -d = -f2
```

For example I would search for "inbound=" and extract the "100". 
But the tricky part is "inbound" won't there in all the lines of the text
Now I would like to print "0" if a line doesn't have the word "inbound".

**Expected output**

```
100
100
0 Not Found
```

Comment: *whatever is after the "="* - fits not only to `inbound`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have name=value pairs in your input it's best to first create an array of those mappings (`f[]` below) and then you can just print (or do anything else with) the values by name:

```
$ awk -v n="inbound" -F'[ =]+' '{delete f; for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print (n in f ? f[n] : "0 Not Found")}' file
100
100
0 Not Found
```

Want to do the same for "outbound" or any other field? Just init the name variable `n` accordingly"

```
$ awk -v n="outbound" -F'[ =]+' '{delete f; for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print (n in f ? f[n] : "0 Not Found")}' file
100
0 Not Found
100
$
$ awk -v n="date" -F'[ =]+' '{delete f; for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print (n in f ? f[n] : "0 Not Found")}' file
"2017-10-10"
"2017-10-10"
"2017-10-10"
$
$ awk -v n="ip" -F'[ =]+' '{delete f; for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print (n in f ? f[n] : "0 Not Found")}' file
192.168.1.1:22
192.168.1.1:22
192.168.1.1:22
```

Comment: You're welcome. From [your followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44340126/1745001), though, I don't think you really understood this answer or why it's different from the other answers you got since it provides the solution for your followup question too.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk

```
awk '{print match($0,/inbound=([0-9]+)/,a)?a[1]:0}' file
```

In perl

```
perl -lne 'print /inbound=(\d+)/?$1:0' file
```

In sed

```
sed 's/.*inbound=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/;t;s/.*/0/' file
```

Comment: @Inian The last arg to match is GNU awk only unfortunately, otherwise you have to mess around with `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`.

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100 outbound=100
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22  outbound=100
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '{if(match($0,/inbound=[0-9]+/)){s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print substr(s,index(s,"=")+1);next}print 0,"Not Found"}' file
100
100
0 Not Found
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '{

    # Search for word inbound=[0-9]+ in record/line/row, if found then
    if(match($0,/inbound=[0-9]+/))
    {
        # Extract word
        s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)

        # Print value which is after "="  
        print substr(s,index(s,"=")+1)

        # Go to next line
        next
    }

      # If above condition is not true then word inbound not found in line/row/record

      print 0,"Not Found"
  }
 ' file
```