# Awk match for multiple patterns in a line and print column if found else print not found

Tags: bash, awk

My test file looks like below

**Input**

```
$ cat file
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100 outbound=50
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22 inbound=100
date="2017-10-10" ip=192.168.1.1:22  outbound=60
```

I use the below awk command to extract values for inbound=.

```
$ awk '{found=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /inbound/) { split($i,arr,"="); print arr[2];found=1 } } if (!found) print 0 }' file
100
100
0
```

Now I would like to add "IP","port" and "outbound" to list so that my output looks like

```
IP,PORT,INBOUND,OUTBOUND

192.168.1.1,22,100,50
192.168.1.1,22,100,0
192.168.1.1,22,0,60
```

Comment: Closing as a dup as I told you **exactly** how to do that in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331032/1745001) - build the array then print whatever values you like by their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
awk '{
    ip=0;
    port=0;
    inbound=0;
    outbound=0;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /ip=/) {
            split($i,arr,"=");
            split(arr[2],arr2,":");
            ip = arr2[1];
            port = arr2[2];
        }
        if ($i ~ /inbound/) {
            split($i,arr,"=");
            inbound=arr[2];
        }
        if ($i ~ /outbound/) {
            split($i,arr,"=");
            outbound=arr[2];
        }
    }
    print ip "," port "," inbound "," outbound
}' file
```